# Angulartics and Google analytics

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I was able to add google analytics and Angulartics to my ionic project by

1. adding the necessary Angulartics files to my project as instructed at http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/
2. Added this code to my config file (**coffescript**)

   ```
   .config ($analyticsProvider, googleAnalyticsCordovaProvider, 
         $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->  

             $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true)

             googleAnalyticsCordovaProvider.trackingId = window.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID
             googleAnalyticsCordovaProvider.debug = true
   ```
3. add in my config.xml file

   ```
   <gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
   ```

I am using **phonegap build** and it works.  I get data on my google analytics page. **What I want to know is how can I add this plugin to my local development or is there a better way to set up Angulartics with ionic and phonegap build?**

When I do this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git
```

or

```
cordova plugin add com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For a phonegap project you could try

```
phonegap local plugin add com.analytics.google
```

You can find the documentation for the plugin here: https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google

If you need it with PGB, you should use:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.analytics.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```